# How to avoid these keepalive@openssh.com log messages when Paramiko Python module is used?

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, sftp, paramiko

I am using Python Paramiko module to do download files from SFTP server.

But it is displaying the following the log messages continuously.

```
Wed Dec 20 06:51:00 2017 transport         line:1572 22192 /PoolWorker-13        139861396514560 Thread-138           DEBUG    Received global request "keepalive@openssh.com"
Wed Dec 20 06:51:00 2017 transport         line:1572 22192 /PoolWorker-13        139861396514560 Thread-138           DEBUG    Rejecting "keepalive@openssh.com" global request from server.
Wed Dec 20 06:51:00 2017 transport         line:1572 22192 /PoolWorker-13        139861395986176 Thread-140           DEBUG    Received global request "keepalive@openssh.com"
Wed Dec 20 06:51:00 2017 transport         line:1572 22192 /PoolWorker-13        139861395986176 Thread-140           DEBUG    Rejecting "keepalive@openssh.com" global request from server.
```

What is the change required to avoid the above lines to be displayed in logs for Paramiko module? I am using Paramiko 2.1.2 module on Python 2.7.6. Will those log lines will be gone if we use pysftp module instead of Paramiko?

Answer (score 4):

Filter them out using [`Logger.addFilter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.addFilter):

```
class KeepalivesFilter (object):
    def filter(self, record):
        return record.msg.find('keepalive@openssh.com') < 0

paramiko.util.get_logger('paramiko.transport').addFilter(KeepalivesFilter())
```

---

(using pysftp won't help as it uses Paramiko internally)